# How to obtain boostrap estimates for multiple parameters

Tags: python

I want to create a function using boostrap to estimates mean and median on multiple parameters. I have been able to generate for a single parameter, but the multiple seems I would need to get a loop that will be able to loop through and return the mean and meadian for me. The code is for single;

```
def get_boostrap_estimates_single_param(sample_size):
    """
    Generate a bootstrap sample but harcode df within the function
    so that we can use Pool.map() later
    :param sample_size: how many rows to sample from the input dataframe
    :returns mean and median of this particular bootstrap sample
    """

    # Load the age.csv file into a dataframe here
    dataPath = '/home/faustus/Documents/Review Courses/Big Data Analysis/age.csv'
    age = pd.read_csv(dataPath, index_col = False)
    
    # shuffle the dataframe by using pd.DataFrame.sample() with
    # n = df.size
    df = pd.DataFrame.sample(age, n = age.size)

    # Get bootstrap sample with replacement
    df_sample = df.sample(sample_size, replace = True)

    # return mean and median
    return df_sample.mean(), df_sample.median()
```

Output:

```
get_boostrap_estimates_single_param(2000)
(age    23.057
 dtype: float64,
 age    19.0
 dtype: float64)
```

Now I want to get for multiple parameters, but instead of hard-coding the dataframe, I want to pass it as an argument using the fuction;

```
def get_boostrap_estimates_multiple_params(df, sample_size):
    """
    Generate a bootstrap sample
    :param df: input dataframe
    :param sample_size: how many rows to sample from the input dataframe
    :returns mean and median of this particular bootstrap sample
    """
```

How can I solve this problem?